# Error: Requested action not taken. file name not allowed

Tags: ftp

I am using UltraEdit for FTP. While saving my files to other server using FTP I am getting above error as ;'Error: Requested action not taken. file name not allowed'.
Could anyone know the possible cause and solution for it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the FTP server returns error code 40553 - Requested action not taken. File name not allowed.

The reason is most likely a bad character in file name, or a too long file name, or there is a file already on the server with same name and you do not have the permissions to overwrite this file.

You could also have made a mistake in the FTP account configuration like a typing mistake in initial directory.

Do you have downloaded the file from the FTP server before you tried uploading it?

Please note that Unix file systems most often used on FTP servers are case-sensitive and therefore a file with name "MyFile.txt" is a different file than "myfile.txt".

Finally, very often a firewall blocks data transfer in a separate data channel established from FTP server to FTP client module in UltraEdit. In this case the option *Passive transfers (for firewalls)* should be enabled on the **Server** tab of this FTP account in the **FTP Account Manager** window.